# No wifi in dropdown options

Tags: networking, 20.04, settings, secure-boot

I am getting this:

```
Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter

Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter

Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state() failed: Invalid Parameter

Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled.
```

When trying to boot ubuntu. It works but theres no wifi option in the dropdown settings or actual settings, and in >network it dosent show anything. How do i fix this?

What I did before this: reinstall Alsa vecause the sound was off pitch then reboot

Everything worked for over 3 months since i installed and used ubuntu on my 2008 model mac

Im quite new to ubuntu so i dont really know much of the commands od shit in it, how do u enter the bios settings?

Comment: did it work before and stopped working or has it never worked?

Comment: @david worked before

Comment: something help there? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1867092